# Angularjs editable drop down in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select, dropdown

I have a table made out of div tags with an ng-repeat to populate the divs from an array. I want to be able to make one of the div options an editable dropdown where the default option is a value stored from the array and the rest of the elements are loaded from another array. When a user selects an element from the drop down, the default option is then changed to whatever they selected. Does anything exist for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try select2 dropdown.I have added a plunkr of the same.
https://embed.plnkr.co/umVG1tVdYJXbrKt0E70Q/

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular [ui-select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/) directive